# Limiting access to local repository

Tags: git

I'm interested in tracking the `/etc`dir locally on my FreeBSD server with `git`, but without compromising the local security of my system.

For instance, the file `/etc/master.passwd` is only readable by `root` and I want it to be that way.

**By this method, however, security was compromised:**

As root, I created a git repository in `/etc`:

```
/etc# git init .
/etc# git add .
/etc# git commit -am "Initial commit"
```

The problem:

Since `/etc` is readable by `someuser`, `someuser` could copy the repository to his own writeable directory and checkout the sensitive file(s), thereby gaining read access:

```
/etc$ cp -Rpv .git /home/someuser/sandbox/.git
/etc$ cd /home/someuser/sandbox
~/sandbox$ git checkout master.passwd
~/sandbox$ cat master.passwd
....
```

What is best practice to prevent this?

Comment: Don't let git track the file e.g. ignore it?

Comment: @TimCastelijns I was hoping there was a way to do this without ignoring every sensitive file.

Comment: Well, you have to "hide" them someway, why not use the tools you're already using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the `.git` folder only viewable by `root` as well.

I.e. give the directory (and all the files in it) the `600` permission (owner can read and write).

Comment: I thought of that, but does this work well with git? I was afraid "tampering" with the permissions of the `.git` dir would make problems for git...

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem, try it and see. (Preferably not on your production server's `/etc` :P)